# Утилита для управления системными сервисами

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-service

Есть около десятка сервисов которые работают в режиме крона - каждые х минут что-то проверяют, отправляют, записывают и т.д. Так как управлять этой стаей становится все труднее, задумал как-то консолидировать все.

Столкнулся с проблемой взаимодействия приложения с сервисами - а именно уведомление десктоп приложения со стороны сервисов. Пока остановился на применение сокетов.

Кто-то делал такое? Может посоветуйте как организовать такое?

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день!
Я походу с чем-то похожим столкнулся, только надо мне было мониторить состояние служб на удаленном сервере, для этой цели использовал WMI - Windows Management Instrumentation. Посмотри может и тебе пригодиться

Comment: не, ну это понятно что буду использовать... больше хотел бы узнать про взаймодейсивие служб и других процессов (приложения либо тоже службы)

Comment: попробуй посмотри 
http://samag.ru/archive/article/634
http://samag.ru/archive/article/605
и поищи продолжение этих статей....глядишь помогут, достаточно интересно. к сожалению более подробно помочь и поведать не могу, так как сам только недавно с этим всем познакомился...